# Echarts showBackground property not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, echarts

I've googled it a lot but no luck so putting it here.

Why is the `showBackground=true` property is not working in my typescript+angularjs app. I'm using `echarts version 4.1.0`.

```
    let data = {
        title: {
            text: 'ECharts'
        },
        tooltip: {},
        legend: {
            data: ['Test']
        },
        xAxis: {
            data: ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"]
        },
        yAxis: {},
        series: [{
            name: 'Test',
            type: 'bar',
            showBackground: true,
            data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
        }]
    };

    this.echartService.setOption(data);
```

[image]

Here is the working example from echarts: [echarts-bar](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-background)

I'm doing exactly same but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've figured it out showBackground property introduced from version 4.7.0[image]